# Python Regex For Parsing String

Tags: regex

Question 1:

I am very new in regex and learning it through practice, I need one help.
I have a string `"http://www.rediff.com/news/special/india-independence-day-special-abhilash-tomy/20130905.htm"><img class="thumbing" alt="Hoisting the Indian flag where no one else has" src="http://imworld.rediff.com/worldrediff/"`

I want a pattern which gives me exactly rediff.com,imworld.rediff.com

Question 2:

In python, regex is there a way by which my full match result should not contain a particular string but that string is used in regex pattern for matching.

Comment: Where is the `imworld` supposed to come from?

Comment: @L3viathan Sorry for missing the info, I have updated the question

Comment: @PrashantPathak in q1 how it is exactly rediff.com,imworld.rediff.com but not www.rediff.com,imworld.rediff.com ?

Comment: @RajaDorji That is I want to know how I can do exactly rediff.com,imworld.rediff.com but not www.rediff.com,imworld.rediff.com using regex. Or we can not do it?

Comment: @PrashantPathak you would include all matches in format (anychars)rediff.com and only exclude if anychars is www? clarify and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python a regular expression search is typically written as:

```
match = re.search(pat, str) #re.search() to find the first match
match = re.findall(pat, str) #re.findall() to find all matches
```

Answer 1:

```
import re
str = '"http://www.rediff.com/news/special/india-independence-day-special-abhilash-tomy/20130905.htm"><img class="thumbing" alt="Hoisting the Indian flag where no one else has" src="http://imworld.rediff.com/worldrediff/"'
matches = re.findall(r'[\w.-]+\.com',str)
for match in matches:
    print match
```

\w -- matches a word char:a letter or digit or underbar [a-zA-Z0-9_]

[\w.-] -- matches a word char or '.' or '-'

[\w.-]+ -- matches 1 or more occurrence of [\w.-]

(backslash)(dot) -- matches for a '.' (dot)

(backslash)(dot)com -- mathces for '.com'

Answer 2:

```
import re
str = '"http://www.rediff.com/news/special/india-independence-day-special-abhilash-tomy/20130905.htm"><img class="thumbing" alt="Hoisting the Indian flag where no one else has" src="http://imworld.rediff.com/worldrediff/"'
tuples = re.findall(r'([\w.-]+)(\.com)',str)
for tuple in tuples:
    print tuple[0]
```

Add parenthesis around the words you want to separate in groups in the pattern.
Pattern `([\w.-]+)(\.com)` will search for essentially `[\w.-]+\.com` only but the result will come in tuples of words which can be adjusted to display the required words only from tuples.

Check this link to understand the regex better: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions